# How to remove UL class in wp_nav_menu?

Tags: menus

How to remove ul-class in wp_nav_menu?

```
'items_wrap' => '%3$s',
'container' => false
```

Adding above does not work.

Comment: Did you try `menu_class` parameter?

Comment: Please specify what "does not work" mean. This is not a valid description. Please file an [edit] and explain what is wrong with your code, what exactly is not happening

Answer (score 4):

To remove ul class from wp_nav_menu, you will have to define `menu_class` to false. Default  wp_nav_menu ul menu class is `menu`.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => false, 'items_wrap' => '<ul>%3$s</ul>', 'theme_location' => 'mainmenu' ) ); ?>
```

I added `mainmenu` as `theme_location`. You should change it to your theme location.

Read full list of args on [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) codex page.

**EDIT:**

To remove id and classes from ul menu you can define your menu like this.

```
'container' => false,
'items_wrap' => '<ul>%3$s</ul>'
```

Comment: <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'footer','container' => false, 'menu_class' => false,) ); ?>   not work

Comment: Please check edit. I have modified your code that will remove ids and classes from UL.

Comment: <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'footer','container' => false,
'items_wrap' => '<ul>%3$s</ul>') ); ?>   It's not work too

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/167071/edit) and explain what exactly is your HTML output right now and how do you want it. This code removes UL classes, I have tested it just now.

Comment: Please check this screenshot http://ssmaker.ru/8b77bc30.png I need to do to look like the left column right. Title - this is the parent page, below are subsidiaries. And now the left speaker seems to ul - class

Comment: Sorry I could not understand single sentence. I will let other help you on this.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove `ul` and `div` from the function `wp_nav_menu()`, you can use this code:

```
if ( function_exists( 'wp_nav_menu' ) ) {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 
        'menu'       => 'main_nav', // main_nav means menu id
        'container'  => '',
        'items_wrap' => '%3$s' 
    ) );
}
```